# "grub error" after deleting Ubuntu 9.10 partition on Windows machine

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, uninstall

I've deleted my Ubuntu 9.10 Linux partition, but when I'm starting Windows, I get a "grub error".

What should I do to run Windows XP and Windows 7 normally?

Comment: Please provide more information: What is the exact error you get? What is your partition layout? What other OS do you have installed? If you have both Win7 and WinXP on the box, which bootloader do you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deleted the linux partition, rest of grub( stage 2 & boot menu) laying in the deleted partition is destroyed resulting in this grub error. What you got to do is remove the grub totally & make a new MBR.

Boot from win 7 installation disc, go to system repair & enter

```
bootsect /nt60 ALL
```

More on win7 procedure [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html)

or You could boot from the winxp cd & enter this command in recovery console :

```
fixmbr
```

Or use linux testdisk utility & choose Write MBR option.

Comment: Booting from the winxp cd will allow the OP to boot XP, but it will NOT boot win7 because the XP bootloader does not recognize win7.

Comment: Am not sure, but I think the MBR code is just to load boot sector of the active boot partition. Thats why generic testdisk MBR could also fix it. Correct me if I am wrong.